# Tumblrのタイトル部分と日付け書式の変更方法

Tags: html, css

Tumblrの無料テーマ
https://dharmatheme.tumblr.com/
を利用して個人の備忘録のようなものを作っりたいです。
https://rum-julep.tumblr.com/post/643969604868292608
↑この画像の「あいう」となってるタイトル部分を見やすくしたいので横の画像の「美しい見出しのデザイン」のようにしたいのですが　このコードは具体的にどこに差し込めば良いのでしょうか？
自分なりに調べて追加CSSというところに日本語にオススメの書体を追加してはみたのですがこの追加仕方で合ってるのでしょうか…
それと出来れば　日付けの書式も日本式に
2021.2.22のようにするにはどうすれば良いでしょう。
初心者の要領を得ない質問の仕方かもで申し訳ないのですがどなたか教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。m(_ _)m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 自分なりに調べて追加CSSというところに日本語にオススメの書体を追加してはみたのですがこの追加仕方で合ってるのでしょうか…

書体の追加に関しては確認できませんでしたが、 `[テーマの編集]` → `[詳細設定]` → `[カスタムCSSを追加]` という流れで画面を選択し、以下のカスタムCSSを入力することで見出しのスタイルを変更することができました（[見本](https://swimmingtreepeace.tumblr.com/)）。

```
h1 {
  background: #b0dcfa; /*背景色*/
  padding: 0.5em;/*文字周りの余白*/
  color: white;/*文字を白に*/
  border-radius: 0.5em;/*角の丸み*/
}
```

> それと出来れば　日付けの書式も日本式に2021.2.22のようにするにはどうすれば良いでしょう。

まずは `[テーマの編集]` → `[HTMLの編集]` へ移動し、HTMLの編集欄をクリックしたうえで `Ctrl` + `F` を押下します。すると編集欄上部に検索用の入力欄が2つ横並びになっているものが表示されるので、ここの左側へ `{DayOfMonth} {Month} {Year}` を、右側へ `{Year}.{MonthNumber}.{DayOfMonth}` を入力し、これらの入力欄の右側にある `All` ボタンをクリックします。以上の作業を終えた後プレビュー・保存をすることで、日付の書式が質問者さんの期待したものに変更されていることが確認できます（[見本](https://swimmingtreepeace.tumblr.com/)）。

Comment: supa様　丁寧な説明ありがとうございました。書体セットの変更はどんな環境でも同じに表示される組み合わせは？とか考え始めたら　私には手に負えないと思い　タイトルだけ画像扱いで変えることにしました。申し訳ありません。日付けは教わった通りにしたら無事変更出来ました！ありがとうございました☆ 家族のPCの空きを借りているのでご報告に時間がかかり申し訳ありませんでしたがありがとうございました☆

Comment: @ぶぶあられ さん> 返信いただきありがとうございます。無事問題が解決できたようで良かったです。もし問題が解決した場合は、回答を承認して[質問を解決済みにして](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1736/32986)‌​いただけると助かります。

Comment: supa様 またまた遅くなり申し訳ありません。ありがとうございました(о´∀`о)